# How to prevent multiple duplicate events from being registered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.4

I have a situation where a .js library is registering a mouseup event to a DOM element. The DOM element is removed, and replaced and the event is re-registered. This causes two duplicate events to be registered. Here is a reproduction for example:

**Please Note:** This is using jQuery version 1.4.4

```
<div id="top">
 <div id="nested">
  <div id="stranded">
   Alien Code
  </div>
 </div>
</div>​

<script type="text/javascript">
 function addLive(){
  $("#stranded").live("mouseup",
   function (e) {
    var node = document.getElementById("stranded");
    var nodeCopy = $(node).clone(true)[0];
    var tar  = document.getElementById("nested");
    tar.appendChild(nodeCopy);
   }
  );
 }
 addLive();
 addLive();
</script>
```

Also, here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zbtK/

How can I prevent the second call to `addLive` from registering the mouse event if one already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addLive(){
 $("#stranded").die("mouseup");
 $("#stranded").live("mouseup",
  function () {
   var node = document.getElementById("stranded");
   var nodeCopy = $(node).clone(true)[0];
   var tar  = document.getElementById("nested");
   tar.appendChild(nodeCopy);
 }
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the event handler before registering the newer better one.

Failing that, if you're issue is with the default handlers, you can ignore them.

I think what you're looking for is preventDefault

```
<script>
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('<div/>')
    .append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
    .appendTo('#log');
});
</script>
```

also you can test for it

For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL. We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event.

Answer (score 1):

You don't exactly tell us what your editing contraints are and what code you can change.

The simplest thing would be to stop using `.live()` and just attach the event directly to the object.  Then, when the object is removed, so is the event handler.

If you can't do that for other reason, then you also keep track of whether the event handler has been installed already, either in a global variable or using jQuery's `.data()` on the `#stranded` element.

P.S. `.live()` has been deprecated and you should be using `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` (jQuery before 1.7) for all versions of jQuery.

Comment: I was more curious if this could be done from inside of the live event handler. `live` is being used because the event is attached before the element is rendered.

Comment: Trying to prevent the second execution of the same event handler is a total hack.  You'd probably have to use a global variable to keep track of state from the previous time it was executing and try to figure out if this is still being triggered from the same event.  It probably could be done, but would be a total hack and is the WRONG way to solve the problem (unreliable, hard to maintain, brittle code, etc...).  I would recommend using a proper coding mechanism to prevent the second event handler installation.

Comment: yeah, i usually don't bother with jQuery unless it is something it is good at. code first, simplify later.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Okay, thanks for the advice, I will look into alternatives.

Comment: @jfriend00: OP can't stop using live, he's using jQ 1.4 - `.on` was introduced in `1.7`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - jQuery recommends `.delegate()` instead of `.live()` for jQ 1.4.  `.live()` has been deprecated in ALL versions of jQuery because it can perform very poorly in some circumstances and it can be replaced with `.delegate()`.  From the `.live()` doc page: `Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks for the heads up (it's been a while since I've used jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

why are you calling addLive() function twice?

remove one, it will work :)

Comment: The example is simple, should I make it more complex? The issue is not that there are two calls, but how to prevent an event being registered the second time.

Comment: don't register it a second time.